# Data validation on api endpoints ? What approach do you guys take?

Tags: mysql, node.js, django, laravel, orm

To provide context to my question, consider this example. We have three tables (these are fictitious)

```
animal -> [id, name]
animal_breed -> [id, name, animal, userId]
animal_registration_table -> [id, userId, breedId]
```

Now i have seen two kinds of devs,

1. One who does not validate if the breedId being inserted actually belongs to the user. They just enter the data to db directly assuming that the app or frontend will send them valid data.
2. One who first checks if the breedId belongs to userId by checking from the animal_breed table

Now i am more of the 2 guy. But i want to know what approach is good, approach 2 requires an additional query or check, or is there a better way to do this by having constraint in db and if so can you help me on directing me to what sort of constraints should i have or any other better alternative, as i don't feel point 1 is a good way to go. (p.s not that highly skilled with db so require direction and help)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specified user who "inserts" the data then there should be a check if this user is the actual user. The front-end has not, and should not have this kind of a choice.

Now about your second question,
If the userId is logically a foreign key, then you should set the corresponding constraint with the `on delete` and `on update` rules and all. Basically you don't want to programmatically do what is supposed to be database rules.

I don't know if i covered your answer or not but this is a good topic to talk about.

Comment: can we apply a constraint in db - e.g  can we have something like for adding data to animal_registration_table the breedId and userID have some constraint that must match the id and userId of animal_breed table. If so can you direct me on how we can do that... I am not that good with sql concepts, still trying to learn it everyday, hope my comment makes sense